# Is there a way to use an image (png) of a QR code for logging into a desktop application using ADB?

Tags: android, mobile, automation, adb, qr-code

I want to try to log into a desktop app, like Discord, using the QR-code log-in option.

The user would usually need to use his phone to scan the QR-code that is displayed on the desktop.

I want to try to automate this proceedure by saving this image in a png format, for example, and using it to log-in through the mobile Discord app using an ADB connection.

I'd like to do this without using the phone camera pointed to the screen, since this wouldn't be possible for my situation. I'd also prefer to avoid emulators.

I've been able to scan the QR-code using python. For example. I scanned the code below:

[Log-in screen on the Discrod Desktop app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMIW2.png)

... and I got back the following link: https://discord.com/ra/fIUSUsnlPHThLkj5ghZtCATW5hxpc7qn00KYe1iJCNw

I know that this is a link that will probably be associated with some API communications in order to get me authenticated and allow the Desktop app to perform the log-in.

But I don't know how I could use this to communicate something with the app, such as "I have my side of the authentication and I need you to take this and allow me to log-in".

I've tried opening it with ADB as if it were a sort of browser link. It successfully opens the app and the camera screen for scanning the code opens quickly, but soon closes saying "Something went wrong when trying to scan."

Is something like this possible? Using an image of a QR-code or a link from this QR-code to "fool" the scanner?

This question is similar to "How can I pass a QR code image to a QR code scanning app, open in appium desktop?", which currently has no answer.

Comment: Unless the app is set up to do this, it isn't going to work.  The QR code links to a URL.  If the discord app is installed on the phone AND logged in AND is set up to handle https://discord.com links so it's launched when you send it an Intent with that as the data AND it handles sign up links byprocessing that as a request to join the server, it would work.  It's unlikely to be set up that way though, because then any malicious app on your phone could sign you up for any discord it wants, which is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, @GabeSechan! I guess I'll have to try to scan the code using an emulator.